# Create a matrix from a data.frame and count common values

Tags: r

I'm trying to understand the cross domain behavior on multiple websites. I have this information

```
Website       ClientID     SessionId
-------------------------------------
domain1          xxx         d.0686
domain2          xxx         d.0686
domain3          yyy         f.1871
domain2          yyy         f.1871
domain4          yyy         f.1871
domain1          zzz         n.9210
domain2          zzz         n.9210
```

People can move across multiple website but they keep the ClientID (stored as a cookie) and the SessionID (shared between different website when a person moves from a domain to another).

I need to see how many SessionID two different websites share. I guess the easiest way is to create a Matrix counting the shared unique SessionIds. This would be the result based on the above table

```
          Domain1     Domain2     Domain3     Domain4 
    --------------------------------------------------------
domain1     0            2          0           0

domain2     2            0          1           1

domain3     0            1          0           0

domain4     0            1          0           0
```

This way I can count how many times two different website are used in the same sessionID and create a Chord Diagram with `circlize()` package to visualise the relation.

Is it possible to do it on R?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.. But SO is not a code producing factory. Show your own effort/code first, and the users will gladly help you improve it.

Comment: The following should be a compulsory read for every new contributor. Give it a read John. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```
domains <- unique(information$Website)
output <- matrix(0, length(domains), length(domains))
colnames(output) <- rownames(output) <- domains

for (x in domains) {
  X <- unique(information[information$Website == x, 'SessionId'])
  for (y in domains) {
    Y <- unique(information[information$Website == y, 'SessionId'])
    output[rownames(output) == x, y] <- length(intersect(X, Y))
  }
}

print(output)

#domain1 domain2 domain3 domain4
#domain1       2       2       0       0
#domain2       2       3       1       1
#domain3       0       1       1       1
#domain4       0       1       1       1
```

## data

```
information <- structure(list(Website = c("domain1", "domain2", "domain3", "domain2", "domain4", 
                                          "domain1", "domain2"), 
                              ClientID = c("xxx", "xxx", "yyy", "yyy", "yyy", "zzz", "zzz"), 
                              SessionId = c("d.0686", "d.0686", "f.1871", "f.1871", "f.1871", 
                                            "n.9210", "n.9210")), 
                         .Names = c("Website", "ClientID", "SessionId"), 
                         row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```